# How to change the default settings of a file/new/project in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, settings, default

For example: I want to have all newly-created C++ projects (libraries, dlls, apps) to treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a different Stack Overflow question (regarding the default setting for Character Set):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/ceef57ef-788e-4666-aea7-cc19c44c1330

It's a bit dated (VS2005) but it might still apply.
Basically, it says to edit the Javascript (JS) scripts that create a new C++ project.
This has to be done on each installation of Visual Studio, because you're editing the locally installed files.

Another option (which I will be looking into) is to create a VS plugin with a "New Project" event handler that alters the project default settings after it is created.